# XMLHttpRequest detecting 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript

If the URL is correct (file.dat exists), this works great (the file length matches).  If it is wrong I will see a very small file length and I will not see the `xhr.onerror`.

How can I detect that the URL was incorrect?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.responseType = "blob"
xhr.onload = ()=> {
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = evt => {
        var contents = new Buffer(evt.target.result, 'binary')
        console.log('file len',contents.length) 
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(xhr.response)
}
xhr.addEventListener("error", () => { console.error('xhr.onerror',e) })
xhr.open("GET", "file.dat")
xhr.send()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

I do see a stacktrace in the console pointing to `xhr.send()`
`GET http://localhost:8080/file.dat 404 (Not Found)`

A try catch around both open and send does not catch any exceptions.

Files are served by WebpackDevServer (I hope that should not matter though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the [status of the response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-status).

```
// Not using arrow function because I don't want the lexical `this`
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 404) {
       // not found, add some error handling
       return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = evt => {
        var contents = new Buffer(evt.target.result, 'binary')
        console.log('file len',contents.length) 
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(xhr.response)
}
```

Credit to https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/129410/xhr-request-cant-check-for-error-for-404-page-or-other-errors

Comment: `this` is undefined in `this.status`...    `xhr.status` works

Comment: @jcalfee314 `this` is not undefined if you use a regular function as I showed in the example. If you use the arrow function, `this` would be pointing to the same thing as `this` outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-status:

XmlHttpRequest objects (you have one in the variable `xhr`) have a read-only property `status` that you can use to get the status text once it's loaded.